# jquery add item to UL then sort, then highlight item that was added

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is my current code

```
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().after("<li>new item on list</li>");
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

what i want is to have the newly inserted li element get highlighted after it is sorted

```
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().after("new item on list");
 $("ul#attachmentlist>li").tsort(); // tinysort plugin
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

i have sorting working, 
how do i get a reference to the newly inserted item, so that when i call the highlight effect, 
it highlights the newly inserted element, not the last one on the list ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you created the object before inserting it?  Then you'd have the correct reference to highlight:

```
var newListItem = $("<li>new item on list</li>");
$('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().after(newListItem);
$("ul#attachmentlist>li").tsort(); // tinysort plugin
newListItem.effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can kick off the effect animation before the sort keeping it still pretty simple, like this:

```
$("<li>new item on list</li>").appendTo('ul#attachmentlist')
                              .effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
$('ul#attachmentlist>li').tsort();
```

This uses the [`$(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) method of creating the element, and just appending it to the parent (thereby making it the last item) and starting an animation at the same time.  Then we do a sort...but the animation will continue to work, even after the elements are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the added Li a class, then remove it after you highlight it. like so:

```
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').last().after("<li class='NewThing'>new item on list</li>");
 $("ul#attachmentlist>li").tsort(); // tinysort plugin
 $('ul#attachmentlist>li').find('.NewThing').effect("highlight", {}, 2000).removeClass('NewThing');
```

Comment: This will add a class to the *previous* last item, not the newly inserted element.

Comment: damn, that's right.  that's what i get for trying to keep the solution close to the original.  Your solution is better!

Comment: i fixed my answer, just incase someone comes across this in the future